# D trigger scheme test

Tags: triggers

[image]I want to test my D trigger scheme and I don't know how to do that. I don't even know how "truth table" works and maybe someone can help/explain how to make a test for my D trigger scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logical table works as follows:

Each row represents a case, each column represents a statement. A cell represents the logical value of a statement. It is wise to differentiate mentally atomic columns from molecular columns. In your case, you have three atomic columns, they represent the cases. These are the first three columns in your logical table. The other columns are molecular columns, that is, their value is composed by other columns.

D is said to be the value of XOR-ing the third and the fifth column. If you look in each row the value of the third and the fifth column in the table, you will see that D4 is true (1) if they differ and it is false (0) if they are similar.

I am not sure what do you mean by testing the D trigger scheme, but if by that you mean that we should test whether the formula matches to the values, then we can say that yes, it matches, since the general concept of XOR is matched in all cases in your logical table.